# File-size limit for attachments while sending mail using mandrill

Tags: java, email, mandrill

What is file-size limit for mandrill attachments?
In mandrill site, they are only giving details about maximum message size.(10MB)

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send any size attachments, as long as the total message size doesn't exceed 25MB.  So if you have an attachment that is 5MB and another that is 2MB and your HTML/text portions are under 1MB, you'd still be under the total message size limitation. Keep in mind that when attachments are Base-64 encoded, they take up 1/3 more space than they do on disk, so if your attachment is 3MB on disk, it would be 4MB once it's Base-64 encoded. You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582407-Does-Mandrill-Support-Attachments-).

Feel free to send us an email, too, if you have other questions or if you have specific questions about your account. You can submit a request at [help.mandrill.com](http://help.mandrill.com).

Comment: Actually the current maximum size of a message is 25MB not 10MB.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore is correct as of Dec/2016, link to docs: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582407-Does-Mandrill-Support-Attachments-

Comment: @BrunoPeres Thanks, I've updated the answer to reflect this.